# How to make =GETPIVOTDATA more dynamic?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with some data that im trying to reference with one sheet and then cross reference it with another to compare the two values.

What I have at the moment is similar tot he formula listed here - http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/pivottbls/getpivotdata2.php

However, instead of writing `=GetPivotData (team_count,"'Team 1' 'Count of B'")` and then changing it for the rest of the cells in my worksheet.

I want to be able to reference cells that contain the data I want to look up. So for example, I would have `Team 1` in cell `A2` and `Count of B` in cell `A3`.

Ive tried rewriting the formula to `=GetPivotData (team_count, A2, A3)` but that just gives me an error :/

Comment: have you tried using INDIRECT around A2 and A3 ?

Comment: I assume you mean something like `=GETPIVOTDATA(team_count,INDIRECT(A2,a3))` that just gives me a `#VALUE` error

Comment: When you entered "Team 1" did you put quotes around it? I tried this in Excel 2007 and if I entered "Team 1" without quotes, the formula worked.

Comment: seems to be 4 arguments in the GETPIVOTDATA formula I'm playing with _=GETPIVOTDATA("amound",$E$17,H16,H15)_ the second argumnet seems to be an anchor to the top left cell of the pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to create a string `"'Team 1' 'Count of B'"` from cells A2 and A3:

`=getpivotdata(team_count, "'" & A2 & "' '" & A3 & "'")`

Answer (score 4):

In order to avoid extra quotes, you can also use the `T()` function:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA( T(team_count), <Ref address of pivottable>, A2, A3)
```

Comment: I needed to use T() for the first argument in the GETPIVOTDATA function, which is the one that says what 'statistic' you're going to get.  (I.e.:  Sum of product_sales.)